# Find all enums in my project

Tags: java, enums

In my project I have a few declared enums. I would like to create a method that loops over all of these and then over all the values of each enum.

Example with two enums:

```
public enum Mood {
    GOOD, BAD;  
}

public enum Weather {
   WET, DRY;
}
```

If I looped over each enum and their values and printed them each on a line, the program would print

```
GOOD
BAD
WET
DRY
```

The order is not important...

If I add a new enum, that should also be printed without having to change the code. I cannot know in what package the enums will be located. Only a root package.

Comment: I assume you don't want the `enums` in the JVM as well?

Comment: Exactly, only my own. They will all be located under the root package.

Comment: I thought you meant it could be any sub-package of root.  Using the root package has been discouraged for many years now.

Comment: You mean no package? I thought that was called "default package". I refer to the top package of my project, eg com.mycompany.myproject

Comment: Ok, so you can search anywhere below a specific package. That will make the search much faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library will help you.

You can search for each class which implements `Enum` and get all the classes values using `clazz.getEnumConstants()`

Comment: It will only work if he has a java file for each enum. Any enum that is declared inside of another class will not be listed.

Comment: Good to know. Fortunately I do have all my enums in separate java files.

Comment: I love reflections but is there a way to find all enumConstants for complete projects? I am sure that there would be some way of doing it, just not sure how...